# changing a button background color in a menu bar and displaying the same back color in child page on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

I have an issue in asp.net Master page, I have 4 buttons as a menu bar and I need to change the color when a button is clicked , I have done this in java script , but when I am redirecting to the child page it is changing the color again to it's initial color.

ASP.NET CODE (button class and focus class have different color):

```
 <div>
   <input type="button" id="t1" class="button" onclick="setColor('tab1', 0)" value="b 1">
   <input type="button" id="t2" class="button" onclick="setColor('tab2', 1)" value="b 2">
   <input type="button" id="t3" class="button" onclick="setColor('tab3', 2)" value="b 3">
 </div>
```

Java script code:

```
function setColor(pos) {
    //var property = document.getElementById(btn);
    var buttons = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".button"));

    // Loop through the buttons
    buttons.forEach(function (btn) {

        // Set up a click event handler for the button
        btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
            if (this.value == "button 1") {
                window.location.href = "Default.aspx";
            } else if (this.value == "button 2") {
                window.location.href = "Default2.aspx";
            } else if (this.value == "button 3") {
                window.location.href = "Default3.aspx";
            }
            // Loop though all the buttons and reset the colors back to default
            buttons.forEach(function (btn) { btn.classList.remove("focus"); });

            // Now, add the class to the one button that got clicked
            this.classList.add("focus");
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Your all four buttons are in master page right?

Comment: Yess in master page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because you're redirecting the page and therefore reloading the `html` and the `css` so everything goes back to it's initial state and you lose the color you changed, but you can do what you want by checking the filename when the page loads and setting the the button's color accordingly, like :

```
document.onload = function() {
    var pathName = window.location.pathname.split('/');
    var fileName = pathName[pathName.length - 1]; 

    switch(fileName) {
        case 'Default.aspx':
            document.getElementById('t1').classList.add("focus");
            break;
        case 'Default2.aspx':
            document.getElementById('t2').classList.add("focus");
            break;
        case 'Default3.aspx':
            document.getElementById('t3').classList.add("focus");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , where do i put this java script code? In the master page?? Or in the child pages?

Comment: On the child pages , but if you have a button to redirect back to the master page, you should add this code to the master page too.

Comment: the document get element will work if I put the script inside the content page head ?? it didn't work for me should I write a code to access elements from the master page?

Comment: i edited my answer to wrap the code inside `document.onload` to wait until the elements are loaded, so you can leave it in the `head` tag, although it's better to put it in a `script` tag right before the `</body>` , it should work if you have the same menu ( same `id` ) on all the pages ( whether it's copy/past or a separate file that you import into each page )

Comment: Okay thank you but one final issue do you know why it is taking two clicks for the button to click and not just one? The code of the button click is on java script as mentioned before, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Please try with below code. you have to put this code in Master page

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {

    var path = window.location.pathname;
    var page = path.split("/").pop();

    var t1 = document.getElementById("t1");
    var t2 = document.getElementById("t2");
    var t3 = document.getElementById("t3");

    t1.classList.remove("focus");
    t2.classList.remove("focus");
    t3.classList.remove("focus");

     switch(page) {
            case 'Default.aspx':
                t1.classList.add("focus");
                break;
            case 'Default2.aspx':
                t2.classList.add("focus");
                break;
            case 'Default3.aspx':
                t3.classList.add("focus");
                break;
        }

    });
```